# Formato de dinheiro JavaScript com AngularJS e jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

Bom dia pessoal.

Seguinte, preciso fazer com que quando o usuário saia com o foco do campo ou quando for digitando ele formate este campo de acordo com o formato de dinheiro, primeiramente no formato brasileiro.

Exemplo: 14700,25 ou 14,00. Sem os pontos, se não o AngularJS não consegue somar.

Porém ao utilizar o código abaixo, a função toFixed(2) retira os zeros das casas decimais e por exemplo se o usuário informar 32, chega a adicionar os dois zeros depois da vírgula, porém ao modificar no model continua 32 e não 32,00. E se não colocar o parseFloat ao modificar o model fica em branco o campo.

Segue o código:

```
    function formatarNumero(id, campo){

    var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('divVendaProdutos')).scope();

    var valor_campo;

    if (campo == 1){
        valor_campo = $('#quantidade' + id)[0].value;
        var amt = parseFloat(valor_campo);
        amt = amt.toFixed(2);
         scope.$apply(function () {
            scope.invoice.items[id].quantidade = parseFloat(amt);
         });
    }

    if (campo == 2){
        valor_campo = $('#valorUnitario' + id)[0].value;
        var amt = parseFloat(valor_campo);
        amt = amt.toFixed(2);
        scope.$apply(function () {
            scope.invoice.items[id].valorUnitario = parseFloat(amt);
        });
    }   
}
```

Qual a melhor maneira de resolver este problema?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Como é o seu controller? Acho que você deveria estar formatando o valor lá dentro, com um filtro do Angular.

Comment: Já tentou usar o filtro currency do Angularjs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilize o [currency](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency) conforme essa documentação.
Você pode especificar inclusive qual o simbolo que separa os números decimais e inteiros e quantas casas decimais deseja

**EDIT:** Esse filtro é apenas para apresentar na tela e/ou formatar após submeter o formulário.
Ficaria assim: `<input ng-model="campoDinheiro" value="{{campoDinheiro | currency:'R$'}}"/>`
Se quiser formatar no controller do AngularJS, ficaria assim:

```
$filter('currency')(campoDinheiro, 'R$')
```

Mas, se você precisa de formatar enquanto o usuário está digitando, [crie uma directive](http://solvedstack.com/questions/angular-input-field-with-a-currency-mask-directive-for-money-format-on-the-fly) para fazer isso. Tenha esse exemplo como base, mas altere `prefix,centsSeparator,thousandsSeparator` conforme você deseja

Comment: Pedro, você poderia explicar *como usar* na própria resposta?

Comment: @bfavaretto Olhe ai se ajuda

Comment: Ótimo Pedro, obrigado

Comment: Obrigado @PedroLaini,  irei testar aqui no projeto com o filter e não a directiva, já que é para quando o usuário tirar o foco do elemento em que ele digitou.

Comment: @PedroLaini, a directiva funcionou, porém o cálculo que multiplicava o preço pela quantidade de itens parou de funcionar. E no exemplo que você me passou tentei fazer assim {{ test * test |json }} para ver se funcionava, porém retornou null, como posso fazer a multiplicação?

Comment: você precisa fazer o cálculo no controller e atribuí-lo a variável... essa notação apenas pega a variável e aplica o filtro, não pode fazer cálculo dentro dela

Comment: Obrigado, descobri como arrumar isto, só que tive que mudar o type do input para number e quando o usuário digita o número é retirado rapidamente. O que fiz foi apenas tirar os . (pontos) assim consegue ser feito o cálculo fora do controller.

Answer (score 7):

Resolução mais simples e padrão.

Utilize o I18n do angularJS assim colocando ele em português irá ficar com virgula em vez de ponto e tudo nos padrões brasileiros

https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n

Só colocar este arquivo em seu código:
https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n/blob/master/angular-locale_pt-br.js

Abraços

Answer (score 2):

Idealmente você não deveria aplicar a formatação no model, mas sim na view, ou seja, no código HTML.

Para aplicar formatação de valores o AngularJS oferece o conceito de **filter**, que você indica no HTML juntamente com o valor a ser formatado.

Por exemplo, para formatar uma caixa de texto em formato monetário você pode usar o seguinte código na página HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="{{valorUnitario | currency}}" />
```

Opcionalmente você pode também informar o símbolo monetário que deverá ser usado pela formatação:

```
<input type="text" value="{{valorUnitario | currency:'R$'}}" />
```

Desta forma a caixa e texto ficará sempre formatada, ainda assim mantendo o valor do model sem formatação, de forma que não irá atrapalhar de forma alguma os cálculos com esse valor.

Comment: Testei desta maneira, porém ao digitar não está colocando os pontos e as virgulas ao tirar o focus do input.

Answer (score 2):

Grande bom dia, você pode usar também o pacote de idiomas do angular, no site do próprio angular você encontra, e quando for mostrar algum campo que precise de formatação, como datas ou valores monetaŕios, o angular já faz o trabalho de colocar sifrão ou formatar para a configuração usada na liguagem escolhida.

Esse tuto traz um passo-a-passo que pode ajudar muito,
[como usar angular locale, hello world](http://imasters.com.br/front-end/javascript/serie-angularjs-usando-locale-angularjs-parte-04/?trace=1519021197&source=single).

No caso pra fazer o download dos locales suportados pelo Angularjs [esse link para o projeto no GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngLocale) exibi toda a lista.